# How to divide a daily sum of one column by the daily sum of another column in a Python Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, calculated-columns, operation

I have a pandas dataframe with a Date Index and 3 columns for several years of data.

How can I calculate the daily sum of column 'C' and divide it by the daily sum of column 'A' and write it into a new column (D)?

```
 Index               A   B    C
2014-01-01 00:15:00  10  9   90    
2014-01-01 00:30:00  11  8   88 
2014-01-01 00:45:00  12  7   84
2014-01-01 01:00:00  13  6   78 
2014-01-01 01:15:00  14  5   70 
2014-01-01 01:30:00  15  4   60 
2014-01-01 01:45:00  16  3   48 
2014-01-01 02:00:00  17  2   34 
2014-01-01 02:15:00  18  1   18 
2014-01-01 02:30:00  19  0    0
2014-01-01 02:45:00  20  1   20 
2014-01-01 03:00:00  21  2   42
...
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Only way I could think of doing it was grouping and then merging back in.
I modified some of the days in your example so there would be different days to group by.

```
import pandas as pd

Dict = {'Dates':['2014-01-01 00:15:00','2014-01-01 00:30:00',
        '2014-01-01 00:45:00','2014-01-02 01:00:00',
        '2014-01-02 01:15:00','2014-01-03 01:30:00',
        '2014-01-03 01:45:00','2014-01-03 02:00:00',
        '2014-01-03 02:15:00','2014-01-03 02:30:00',
        '2014-01-04 02:45:00','2014-01-04 03:00:00'],
        'A':[10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21],
        'B':[9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0,1,2],
        'C':[90,88,84,78,70,60,48,34,18,0,20,42]}

df = pd.DataFrame(Dict)
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Dates'])
df.set_index('Dates',inplace=True)

DailySums = df.groupby(df.index.date).sum()
DailySums['D'] = DailySums.C / DailySums.A
DailySums.index = pd.to_datetime(DailySums.index)

df1 = pd.merge(df, DailySums[['D']], left_on=df.index.date, 
    right_on=DailySums.index.date,how='left').set_index('key_0')
```

Will give you:

```
             A  B   C         D
key_0                          
2014-01-01  10  9  90  7.939394
2014-01-01  11  8  88  7.939394
2014-01-01  12  7  84  7.939394
2014-01-02  13  6  78  5.481481
2014-01-02  14  5  70  5.481481
2014-01-03  15  4  60  1.882353
2014-01-03  16  3  48  1.882353
2014-01-03  17  2  34  1.882353
2014-01-03  18  1  18  1.882353
2014-01-03  19  0   0  1.882353
2014-01-04  20  1  20  1.512195
2014-01-04  21  2  42  1.512195
```

Comment: I think using the `transform` method on the groupby object would give you a bit of a cleaner syntax. Shooting from the hip: maybe something like `df['D'] = df.groupby(...).transform(lambda g: g['A'].sum() / g['C'].sum())`

Comment: @ Liam Foley:  in the line "DailySums = df.groupby(df.index.date).sum()" I am getting the Error that "AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex object has no attribute 'date'

Comment: @Paul H: I have tried your solution as it seems really lean :-) Unfortunately the groupby runs into an 'Assertion Error' within resample.py

Comment: @MarkusW I think you actually need to group by a `pandas.TimeGrouper` (or something like that -- I'm away from my machine). That object takes either a string (`1D`) or a `pandas.Offset` object. I'll try to get more specifics when I'm in front of a machine later.

Comment: I have tried the following:   "grouper = pd.TimeGrouper('1D')" followed by "df['D'] = df.groupby(grouper).transform(lambda g: g['A'].sum() / g['C'].sum())" and managed to get a new error-message: "AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'ndim'"

Comment: It definitely does though... http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html#pandas.DatetimeIndex.date
Did you use pd.to_datetime?